# IMPORTRANGE excluding all rows that come after the first empty row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, importrange

I'd like to know how can I can import a range excluding all rows from the source that come after the first empty row.

For example, let's say I have a sheet with 200 rows, but the row 101 is empty, but from 102 to 200 all rows have values. I'd like to import only rows 1:100.

I need to do it independently of how many rows has the source sheet, because we regularly import data and the number of valid rows grows on every import.

Comment: Welcome to stack: Please edit your question and show us your code explain what is not working with your current solution.   Also please fix your tags Google-drive-api and Google-query-language are not related to google Sheets.

Comment: Is this from Sheet to Sheet or from Sheet to Doc? Is it's sheet to sheet then `range.getValues()` and `range.setValues()` would be better to use than `importrange`

Comment: @RafaGuillermo The question isn't about Google Apps Script., IMPORTRANGE is a built-in formula.

Comment: As I mentioned on my previous comment IMPORTRANGE is a built-in function. Is your question about this built-in function and Google Sheets formulas or are you looking to use Google Apps Script or the Google Sheets API? Besides answering this also add a brief description of your search research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 0):

it would be like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IMPORTRANGE("ID_or_URL", "Sheet3!F1:F"&MIN(IF(
 IMPORTRANGE("ID_or_URL", "Sheet3!F1:F")="", ROW(A:A), ))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what's already here, if you would like to do this more generically using Apps Script, you can bind this to the sheet and run as you need.

Assuming that Column A is being used for the data in the Sheet to Copy to, you can find the first row which is blank by running

```
function obtainFirstBlankRow() {  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SHEET-TO-COPY-TO');
  // search for first blank row
  var col = sheet.getRange('A:A');
  var vals = col.getValues();
  var count = 0;

  while (vals[count][0] != "") {
    count++;
  }
  return count + 1;
}
```

This will return a number corresponding to the first row in which the cell in the A column is blank - you can change which column it checks if you need by replacing `A:A` in `sheet.getRange()` to the range you need.

You can then use:

```
function myFunction() {  
  var startRow = 1; //assuming you want to copy from row 1
  var endRow = obtainFirstBlankRow();
  var startCol = 1; // assuming you want to copy starting at column A
  var endCol = 26; // assuming copying values up to column Z
  var startRowPaste = 1; //assuming you want to copy starting at row 1
  var startColPaste = 1; // assuming you want to copy starting at column A

  //example range to copy from
  var rangeToCopy = SpreadsheetApp.openById('IDOfSheetToCopyFrom').getSheetByName('SheetToCopyFrom')
  var rangeToCopy = rangeToCopy.getRange(startRow, startCol, endRow, endCol);

  //make sure the range you're copying to is the same size
  var newRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById('IDOfSheetToCopyTo').getSheetByName('SheetToCopyTo')
  var newRange = newRange.getRange(startRowPaste, startColPaste, rangeToCopy.getNumRows(), rangeToCopy.getNumColumns()); 
  newRange.setValues(rangeToCopy.getValues());
}
```

To copy the data to the new Range.